# Sigmoid Curve fit in MathNet Numerics

Tags: c#, math, math.net

I have a 3rd degree polynomial fit in MathNet and tested that it works

However, the application here is for edge finding, and I need to do an S-curve fit,
I cannot find the correct function for this.

Essentially this would be a rotated polynomial fit as shown below, where the start and finish are horizontally asymptotic, not vertically.

The example below shows the Polynomial curve fit I have right now

```
            double[] xdata = new double[] { 0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
            double[] ydata = new double[] { 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1};

            double[] p = Fit.Polynomial(xdata, ydata, 3);
```

Result looks like the curve below, as you can see the start and end are not horizontal

What curve fit do I need to use in MathNet to get an S shaped or sigmoid result?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?